# is this .xml.dist file really required to be used

Tags: php, magento, selenium, phpstorm

we have been using Selenium for a while and alot of the time it breaks for some reason, when we debug i am constantly being chewed out by the guy on my team who created the somewhat step-by-step guide to install Selenium and Magewnto TAF about my use of a phpunit.xml file that i copied from the original phpunit.xml.dist

he says that we **HAVE** to use the .dist file and that the reason why my Selenium and Magento TAF doesn't work in Firefox anymore is because i don't do what he does, i on the other hand have always believed that like .[EXT].bak files, .[EXT].dist files are just used for distribution and are the default setup, people who want to customize the setup would copy and remove the .dist and use that, he argument that i am wrong is that the phpunit.xml.dist is used in Magento TAF

using Ransack i find only one use for phpunit.xml.dist in `[ROOT]\framework\tests\unit\tests\Mage\Selenium\Helper\FileTest.php` which is this function

```
/**
 * @covers Mage_Selenium_Helper_File::loadYamlFile
 * @depends test__construct
 *
 * @expectedException InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function testLoadYamlFileException()
{
    $fileHelper = new Mage_Selenium_Helper_File($this->_config);
    $this->assertFalse($fileHelper->loadYamlFile(SELENIUM_TESTS_BASEDIR . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'phpunit.xml.dist'));
}
```

now my programming knowledge is built from me developing games in my spare time so i've normally seen .dist files used in public scripts and systems and they say to customize copy and remove the .dist from the file,

i am wondering, given the function above, is there any reason as to why i **HAVE** to use phpunit.xml.dist rather than copying it, remove the .dist at the end and making my changes to that, i should also note that we use PHP Storm to run the tests so we use the `Defined in the configuration file` option to control which sets we run/debug