# Is there any difference in naming the PHPunit configuration file phpunit.xml.dist or phpunit.xml

Tags: php, xml, symfony, unit-testing, phpunit

Can someone explain to me what is the difference between using PHPunit configuration files named `phpunit.xml.dist` or `phpunit.xml`.

The [official documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html#organizing-tests.xml-configuration) mentions both names:

> PHPUnit's XML configuration file (Appendix C) can also be used to compose a test suite. Example 5.1 shows a minimal phpunit.xml file that will add all *Test classes that are found in *Test.php files when the tests directory is recursively traversed.

with giving `phpunit.xml` a higher priority when loading configuration without the `configuration` parameter.

> If phpunit.xml or phpunit.xml.dist (in that order) exist in the current working directory and --configuration is not used, the configuration will be automatically read from that file.

I did find some questions (e.g. [is this .xml.dist file really required to be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304196/is-this-xml-dist-file-really-required-to-be-used)) relating to the fact, that `.dist` files usually are used as a template (distribution) which should be copied to a version without the `.dist` ending to activate them (e.g. `.htaccess.dist`). But this seems not to be the case with PHPunit as it picks up and runs the dist file as well. Other questions ([Can I use phpunit.xml for credentials and phpunit.xml.dist for testsuites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41821429/can-i-use-phpunit-xml-for-credentials-and-phpunit-xml-dist-for-testsuites)) seem to deal with other weird usage ideas about these two files.

In the Symfony world, it is mandatory [for reusable bundles](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html) to include a `phpunit.xml.dist` file and I wonder why not a `phpunit.xml` file instead.

> A test suite must not contain AllTests.php scripts, but must rely on the existence of a phpunit.xml.dist file.

So if anyone can shed some light onto this I would be happy ;-)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If `phpunit.xml` or `phpunit.xml.dist` (in that order) exist in the current working directory and `--configuration` is not used, the configuration will be automatically read from that file.

The idea behind the fallback (to `phpunit.xml.dist` when `phpunit.xml` does not exist) is that `phpunit.xml.dist` can be checked into version control and `phpunit.xml` can be ignored from version control. This allows a developer to use a custom configuration without running the risk of accidentally checking it into version control.

Comment: I understand the concept behind the usage of dist files and possibility of ignoring them in vcs, but I was a wondering because both of them where executed.

Comment: PHPUnit does not use both them. It's either one or the other. With the precedence outlined above.

Answer (score 4):

File .dist are versioned with git for example and you usually don't version `phpunit.xml` because is a configuration file of your machine.

File .dist are often configuration files which do not contain the real-world deploy-specific parameters

If there is phpunit.xml and `phpunit.xml.dist` phpunit takes `phpunit.xml`

`phpunit.xml.dist` It's a standard file, phpunit.xml It's a customization  and aren't versioned to avoid publishing personal data